# Wake up iOS app when app state is closed using corebluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am creating an iOS app with CoreBluetooth and BLE.When BLE peripheral device detects central(APP) peripheral wants to send data to central. If central is in foreground it works fine. How do i wakeup a not running app when device receives a signal. Whether it is possible to wakeup not running app.

Comment: Have you looked at implementing CoreBluetooth's State Preservation and Restoration feature?

Answer (score 0):

You CANT wake up app with a BLE peripheral device, only iBeacon CAN.

Read this answer to know more
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24590886/1005570

> An iBeacon can wake up your app into the background using monitoring APIs. It can do this even if your app has not been launched since device reboot, or even if the app has been killed from the task switcher (although the latter requires iOS 7.1+) This works by your app calling the startRangingBeaconsInRegion: method on CLLocationManager, and also implementing the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol's locationManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:,  locationManager:didEnterRegion: and/or locationManager:didExitRegion: methods.